# ¿ Cuál es le differencia entre PostJsonAsync y PostAsJsonAsync en Blazor?

Tags: c#, blazor

Hola alguien podria explicarme la differencia entre la methodo PostJsonAsync y PostAsJsonAsync en Blazor

```
 private UserInfo userInfo = new UserInfo();
    public async Task CreerUsario()
    { 
        var result = await http.PostAsJsonAsync<UserToken>("api/cuentas/crear", userInfo );
        await loginService.Login(result.Content.ToString());
        Nav.NavigateTo("index");
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

supongo que te refieres a la diferencia entre "PostJsonAsync" y "PostAsync"

**PostAsJsonAsync** parsea el objeto que pasas como parámetro (en este caso userInfo) a un Json de tipo UserToken.

Mientras que a **PostAsync** le pasas por parámetro un HttpContent, algo como:

```
var content = new StringContent(request, Encoding.UTF8,"application/json");
```

O algo como:

```
HttpStreamContent content = new HttpStreamContent(stream.AsInputStream());
```

y lo mandas

```
http.PostAsync(Uri, content);
```

Comment: gracias por tu respuesta

Answer (score 0):

Creo que te refieres a "PostJsonAsync" y "PostAsync"
PostAsJsonAsync parsea el objeto que pasas como parámetro (en este caso userInfo) a un Json de tipo UserToken.
ostAsync le pasas por parámetro un HttpContent.